# Illegal operator and value combination when paginating in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination, laravel-6

I am a newbie at Laravel 6. In the view, I created a form, and when it's submitted, it should return a table filtered with the links of pagination at the bottom. All works correctly, but when I click a link of the pagination appears the following error: "Illegal operator and value combination."

I tried even using the "render" method in the view, but nothing changed. I see the links, but when I click one of them, the error appears.

**View**

```
@if (isset($meetings))
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Participants</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Room</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Start Hour</th>
                <th>End Hour</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($meetings as $meeting)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->id_participants }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->id_room }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->start_hour }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $meeting->end_hour }}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{ route('updateMeeting', ['id' => $meeting->id]) }}" class= "text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></a></td>
                        <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('nextMeetingsDeleteMeeting', ['id' => $meeting->id]) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id={{ $meeting->id }}>Delete</button>
                        </form>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            {{ $meetings->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Controller**

```php
public function fetch_table(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'start_date' => 'date',
        'end_date' => 'date',
    ]);

    $start_date = $request['start_date'];
    $end_date = $request['end_date'];
    $participants = $request['participants'];
    $room_input = $request['rooms'];

    $rooms = Room::all();
    $users = User::all()->where('is_active', '1')->sortBy('surname');

    $meetings = $this->build_table($room_input, $start_date, $end_date, $participants);

    return view('reportArea', compact('users', 'rooms', 'meetings', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'participants',
        'room_input'))->withInput($request->all());
}

public function build_table($room, $start_date, $end_date, $participants)
{
    if (!empty($room) && !empty($participants)) {
        $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
            ->where('is_active', '1')
            ->where('id_room', $room)
            ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
            ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($participants) {
                $query->where('id_participants', $participants)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', $participants.';%')
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants.';%');
            })
            ->paginate(2);
    } elseif (!empty($participants)) {
        $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
            ->where('is_active', '1')
            ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
            ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($participants) {
                $query->where('id_participants', $participants)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', $participants.';%')
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants.';%');
            })
            ->paginate(2);
    } elseif (!empty($rooms)) {
        $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
            ->where('is_active', '1')
            ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
            ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
            ->where('id_room', $room)
            ->paginate(2);
    } else {
        $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
            ->where('is_active', '1')
            ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
            ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
            ->paginate(2);
    }

    return $meetings;
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/reportarea/fetchtable', 'ReportAreaController@fetch_table')->name('reportAreaFetchTable');
```

Currently, all works OK, but when I click a link, the mentioned error appears. In other words, if I add the method `paginate(2)` I see correctly only two rows on the table, but when I click the link to see the other ones, it doesn't work correctly. Is anyone able to help me solve this problem?

Comment: are `start_date`, `end_date`, `participants`, `rooms` query string parameters?

Comment: Yes they are query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to be **appending** to the query string for the links for the pager to pass your other parameters you need. You are passing `null` as a value for those query parameters and getting the error.

As an example:

```
{{ $meetings->appends(['start_date' => ..., 'end_date' => ..., ...])->links() }}
```

Or just passing all the current query parameters (the paginator will ignore what ever key is used for the current page):

```
{{ $meetings->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Pagination - Displaying Results - Appending To Pagination Links](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Requests - Retrieving Input - Retrieving Input From The Query String](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input)